# Widget is not showing when using gridview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to display the note sections in app home screen, but when i'm using the grid view or list view (i dn't know which one causing the issue) the widget is not showing, here is the code

```
SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 32, top: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    'Notes',
                    style: GoogleFonts.righteous(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 36),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 32, top: 20),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      child:
                          Image.asset('asset/bill-gates-wealthiest-person.jpg'),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            Container(
                height: 38,
                width: 323,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFF262636),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    suffixIcon: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        'asset/search.svg',
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 119, 119, 119),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
            SizedBox(height: 49),
            GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              children: List.generate(
                  10,
                  (index) => NoteItem(
                        id: index.toString(),
                        content: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,',
                        title: 'Text $index',
                      )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

and the widget called notapp's code here

```
class NoteItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String content;

  const NoteItem(
      {Key? key, required this.id, required this.title, required this.content})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (ctx) => AddNotes(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 259,
        width: 167,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFF3B3A4D), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
              child: Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
              child: Text(
                content,
                maxLines: 12,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

whats the problem here, i try to fix all the way i can, but its seems like i miss something

expecting screen
[image]

but whats showing is
[image]

Comment: will you try "shrinkWrap: true" in your gridView widget

Comment: wow its worked. thank you, can you explain whats that?

Comment: and its not scrollable tho, why?

Comment: follow this link "https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html#:~:text=shrinkWrap%20property%20Null%20safety&text=Shrink%20wrapping%20the%20content%20of,whenever%20the%20scroll%20position%20changes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not stating any dimension to an item inside column. You can just simply wrap the Gridview.count into an Expanded widget. Check the following implementation:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children:[
        Container(
                height: 38,
                width: 323,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFF262636),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    suffixIcon: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text('Search', style: Text),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
            SizedBox(height: 49),
        Expanded(
        child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              children: List.generate(
                  10,
                  (index) => NoteItem(
                        id: index.toString(),
                        content: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,',
                        title: 'Text $index',
                      )),
            )),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it is working too, but height is like fixed, how can i increase height again, it is not increasing when change the hieght value

Comment: which height value are you changing? Your gridview.count is a child of expanded widget, so it will take up all the available space you have in your view. Expanded widgets expand to all available space

Comment: thats not what i mean, look at the image its a rectangle with deferent height and width, but when this is using it is being square rectagle shape, how do i fix that

Comment: so you are talking about the size n width of NoteItem?

Comment: yes, but the problem wast this, but you cleared that, now facing the sixxe problem

Comment: To change gridview item height, you have to use childAspectRatio like this:
GridView.count(
..other parameters,
childAspectRatio: 2.0
)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap GridView or ListView widget into Expanded() widget:

```
Expanded(
    child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          children: List.generate(
              10,
              (index) => NoteItem(
                    id: index.toString(),
                    content: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,',
                    title: 'Text $index',
                  )),
        ),
),
```